# How can I get the ID of any element clicked within the $(document) in jQuery/js?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).click(function(e){
     alert(e.target); 
});
```

That alerts [Object HTMLDivElement], is there another variable with the ID of the object?

Answer (score 5):

```
alert($(e.target).attr("id"));
```

or

```
alert(e.target.id);
```